# html ul style css for bullet

Tags: html, css

I've following the code.
But there is no style for ul in the class "listStyle".

```css
.listStyle {
    color: red;
} 
.listStyle p {
    color: black;
}

ul li{list-style-type:none;}

.liststyle ul, .liststyle li{list-style-type:circle;list-style:circle;display:inline;}
```

```html
<ul class="listStyle">
    <li>
        <p><strong>View :</strong> blah blah.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p><strong>View :</strong> blah blah.</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to set the circle style for ul that has class "listStyle".
And the rest has to be have none style.
What do I have to fix?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There where two little mistakes in your code:

1. upper and lower case must be same in HTML and CSS
2. if your `<ul>` has a class like `<ul class="list-style">` then the CSS is `ul.list-style`

```css
.listStyle {
    color: red;
} 
.listStyle p {
    color: black;
}

ul li {
  list-style-type:none;
}

ul.listStyle li {
  list-style-type: disc;
}
```

```html
<ul class="listStyle">
    <li>
        <p><strong>View :</strong> blah blah.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p><strong>View :</strong> blah blah.</p>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>list with no bullets</li>
  <li>list with no bullets</li>
  <li>list with no bullets</li>
  <li>list with no bullets</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: When setting to li style like the following.     liststyle li{display:inline;list-style-type:disc;}   I

Comment: In other way, there is a "inline" in the li style, how could I have to display circle bullet for ul?

Comment: @AndrewLi not sure if I understand you correctly. But setting something like a bullet on the `<ul>` (why so ever) could be solved with pseudo class `:before` see here the last example: https://jsfiddle.net/gusqabq4/1/ is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: I've edited for css for my question. I mean when adding "display:inline" to li tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you write `list-style-type: none` you are rejecting the bullet. Remove it and it works.

### EDIT

You can reset the list style type for the classname. see edited snippet. And not that CSS is case sensitive. `liststyle !== listStyle`

```css
.listStyle {
    color: red;
} 
.listStyle p {
    color: black;
}


 ul li{list-style-type:none;}
.listStyle, .listStyle li { list-style-type: circle; }
```

```html
<ul class="listStyle">
    <li>
        <p><strong>View :</strong> blah blah.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p><strong>View :</strong> blah blah.</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.listStyle {
    color: red;
} 
.listStyle p {
    color: black;
}

.nostyle{list-style:none;}

.liststyle ul, .liststyle li{list-style-type:circle;}
```

```html
<ul class="listStyle">
    <li>
        <p><strong>View :</strong> blah blah.</p>
    </li>
    <li class="nostyle">
        <p><strong>View :</strong> blah blah.</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

itz working ...
 if you not want list style mean list-style: none